# I'm trying to create my own custom direct in my angular app for the ladda loading indicator by i see

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to create a ladda loading indicator directive in my angular app and I seem to be getting a error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
>   ....

I don't know what's causing it but here is my code for the directive:

```
.directive('laddaButton', [function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var Ladda = window.Ladda;
            var ladda = Ladda.create(element[0]);
            scope.$watch(attrs.laddaButton, function(newVal, oldVal){
                if(newVal){
                    ladda.start();
                }
                else{
                    ladda.stop();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the info you need is in the error message:

> Cannot call method 'create' of undefined ....

This means the object you're calling `create` on, is `undefined`.

In these lines:

```
var Ladda = window.Ladda;
var ladda = Ladda.create(element[0]);
```

`Ladda` is undefined, so `window.Ladda` is undefined.

Comment: so window.Ladda needs to be defined?  So how do i fix!

Comment: What is `window.Ladda` supposed to be?